# CS50 - Stuck with mario pyramid

Tags: c, cs50

has been doing pset1 "Mario Pyramid" and got stuck with the part about print "Hashes", already tried different ways but... nothing. In specific the problem is where it defines the value of "hs". https://docs.cs50.net/problems/mario/more/mario.html Here is about the problem pset1

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

int main(void)
{
    int h, s, hs, i;

    do {
        h = get_int("Height: ");
    } while (h < 0 || h > 23);

    for (i = 0; i < h; i++) {
        /* ignore 1 */
        if (i < 1) {
            printf("");
        } else {
            for (s = (h - i); s > 1; s--) {
                /* Spaces */
                printf(" ");
            }

            for (hs = 2; hs < h; hs++) {
                /* Hashes */
                printf("#");
            }

            /* Jump Line */
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Height: 6
    ####
   ####
  ####
 ####
####
```

When its supposed to look like a half pyramid

Comment: And we are assumed to know what pset1 is, I guess?

Comment: Is your question related to the one in the link below?  (That site, by the way, might be more appropriate for your question if you still need a separate answer.) https://cs50.stackexchange.com/questions/14083/mario-pyramid-upside-down

Comment: Sorry about that, is mario less comfortable, half pyramid

Comment: That is unreadably unclear to me, still, even with (or maybe because of) that comment.

Comment: You are talking about this course homework assignment, aren't you? https://docs.cs50.net/problems/mario/more/mario.html If yes please summarize shortly directly in your question as explanation and add this link for further reference.

Comment: Yeah, is that one. Already put it in the question

Comment: Thanks for adding the link, but please also summarize, every post on StackOverflow is supposed to still make sense even if the links are lost/unavailable.

Comment: What do you mean by 'stuck with the part about print "Hashes"'. It seems that you found out how to print a hash.

Comment: Please show your output. Please explain how your output is wrong. Please use phrases like "missing newline", "unwanted newline", "missing space", "unwanted space", "wrong number of lines", "wrong number of characters in one line".

Comment: I Already put a img about the output, thanks.

Comment: It is an external link to a picture of text. Please do not link externally if not necessary, please do not post pictures of textual information (i.e. it is not necessary). Please do describe the output, it will lead to the solution. I am referring to the compromise described here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: In addition to the phrases offered above, you might like to describe what is wrong with your output using something like "in line N, I want N hashes, but I get H (height) hashes. So I have H-1-N hashes where I want spaces." Or "the indentation I already got correct, but then the number of hashes is always H-1, but it should be changing with the line number". If you describe your problem like that, then you will most likely discover the path to the solution.

Comment: *After* delivering your assignment, you could experiment some of the `printf` format specifier: https://ideone.com/v7HApd

Comment: There are 31 entries found by the search '`[cs50] mario`' and 49 entries found by '`[cs50] pyramid`'.  Mot will help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before you start coding, try to understand how to solve this problem with pencil
and paper.

Specially when you do a course on computer science, it's more important to
understand the underlying principle more than the programming itself. Very often
you will need to figure out the pattern. Once you've done that, translating it
into a program is much easier.

So let us try to figure out the pattern here.

This is the pyramid you want

```
   #  #
  ##  ##
 ###  ###
####  ####
```

What is the first thing that you can observe? We only have to look at the left
half of the pyramid, because the right half is the same only mirrored.

So the problem becomes easier:

```
   #              |   #
  ##      -->     |  ##
 ###              | ###
####              |####
```

I added `|` to make it clear where each line begin. So for a pyramid of 4:

- we need 4 lines
- every line has the same length, 4 characters
- the number of spaces decrease and the number of hashes increase from top to
  bottom:

  - for the first line  we need 4-1=3 spaces and 1 hash
  - for the second line we need 4-2=2 spaces and 2 hashes
  - for the third line we need 4-3=1 spaces and 3 hashes
  - for the fourth line we need 4-4=0 spaces and 4 hashes

  Are you beginning to see the pattern here?

So in computing we start counting at 0. Beginners often make the mistake to
start counting by 1. So let's repeat these sentences from 0:

- for the 0th line we need 4-1-0=3 spaces and 0+1=1 hashes
- for the 1st line we need 4-1-1=2 spaces and 1+1=2 hashes
- for the 2nd line we need 4-1-2=1 spaces and 2+1=3 hashes
- for the 3rd line we need 4-1-3=0 spaces and 3+1=4 hashes

*thus* for a pyramid of size *n*:

- for the 0th line we need *n*-1-0 spaces and 0+1=1 hashes
- for the 1st line we need *n*-1-1 spaces and 1+1=2 hashes
- · · ·
- for the *n*-1th line we need *n*-1-(*n*-1) spaces and (*n*-1)+1 hashes

Do you see the pattern again?

- for the *i* th line we need *n - 1 - i* spaces and *i+1* hashes.

We have the pattern for the left half, the right half is the same, just
mirrored. So now that we know the numbers of spaces and hashes, writing a loop
is very easy, you almost only have to plug in the formulas:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int n = 10, i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        // left half
        for(j = 0; j < n-1-i; ++j)
            printf(" ");
        for(j = 0; j < i + 1; ++j)
            printf("#");

        // 2 spaces in the middle
        printf("  ");

        // right half, we swapped the order
        for(j = 0; j < i + 1; ++j)
            printf("#");
        for(j = 0; j < n-1-i; ++j)
            printf(" ");

        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note that the right half reverses the order of the printing hashes and spaces.
But trailing spaces at the right can be omitted entirely, so the last `for` loop
can be removed:

```
        // this for loop before the printf("\n");
        // can be removed, not needed.
        for(j = 0; j < n-1-i; ++j)
            printf(" ");
```

When solving these kind of problems, try using this method, pick a
pencil and paper and solve it by hand. Doing
this we've figured out the patter and translating it into code was a piece of
cake. Notice that we even saw that the problem could be "cut in half" because
of the symmetry. Now an exercise for you: print the same pyramid but upside down.